# How to extract latitude and longitude from geoshape point property value in Janusgraph Gremlin?

Tags: clojure, gremlin, janusgraph

I'm new to JanusGraph database and Gremlin query language. I was able to add a property with datatype GeoShape.

```
gvkloc = graph.makePropertyKey("gvkloc").dataType(Geoshape.class).make()
gvk = graph.addVertex(T.label, 'gvk', 'code', 'gvkm', 'gvkloc', Geoshape.point(17.419803, 78.448399))
```

Now my intention is to get the lat and long individually.

```
g.V().has('loc', geoWithin(Geoshape.circle(17.4337, 78.5016, 5))).values('loc')

POINT (78.4712 17.4496)
```

I tried the above code but not able to find perfect solution to extract two points separately as the above query only returning point. Could you please help me with my problem?

Comment: are you trying to write the answer in `clojure`?

Comment: Hi @ArthurUlfeldt Yes. Thank you for understanding. Yes, I have to convert the result of the query into json to display as response. Can you please help here? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? The above looks like plain Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getLatitude() and getLongitude() classes by applying on point(lat, long) .
Look at the [janusgraph documentation](http://snurran.sics.se/hops/alex/janusgraph/jn/janusgraph-0.3.1-hadoop2/javadocs/index.html?org/janusgraph/core/attribute/Geoshape.Point.html)